# Following Django tutorial, "python manage.py migrate" doesn't create any django tables (MySQL, Pycharm)

Tags: python, mysql, django, pycharm

In mysite.settings.py  I have:

```
   DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test'),
        #'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }}
```

When I run 'python manage.py migrate' in the PyCharm terminal, nothing happens, no error message etc. No new tables are created in the database specified. I tried two things for NAME as you can see.

MySQL Server version 8.0.19
MySQL Connector/Python 8.0.19
Python version 3.8
In PyCharm I have package mysqlclient 1.4.6 installed.

Any advice on how to find the problem? How to get an error message?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATABASES` property specifies your DB configurations. Now `NAME` is the property which specifies your database name.

Currently here `'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test'),` won't work as it will give you something like `C:/YourUser/YourPath...` so this string is not a valid db name. `basically (os.path.join() returns a path to your project directory)`

First create a db manually on MySql, note the name and put it in property as `'Name': DBNAME` in `SETTINGS.py`.

(Make sure you have your environment set while running following commands)
Then try `python manage.py makemigrations` for checking migration changes, if everything goes fine up till here then fire `python manage.py migrate` command.

Comment: Yes I have already tried "First create a db manually on MySql, note the name and put it in property as 'Name': DBNAME in SETTINGS.py.". What do you mean exactly by having the environment set? MySQL server service is running, the database is created and ready. What am I meant to see when I do "python manage.py makemigrations"? Because nothing happens. Thank you

Comment: By environment I mean [virtual environment](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/). Generally it is a good practice to have an environment for managing python applications dependencies. Consider virtual environments as a container which provides isolation from your global level python distribution. If you haven't set any virtual environment don't worry as your dependency will be managed by your global python distribution. Still you can run those commands. Run it on your pycharms/cmd/bash terminal.

Comment: Fixed it. Uninstalled all other versions of Python I had other than 64 bit version 38, and changed to virtual environment as you suggested. Thanks